# Show only checked items from database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code. I have a table new-space includes four fields(drive, wikis, task, chat).database connection is OK. Every fields has only value 0 or 1. I want to show those field has value 1. I don't know what will be query. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'hello');
```

Comment: can you expain the table structure clearly ? And how the result should be?

Comment: Need an example of the before and after of records.

Answer (score 0):

First:SeLECT the field using query where value=1

$sql="SELECT * from table_name Where values='1'";

And

Display content using mysql_fetch_array function.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `new-space`";
$data = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
    $result[] = $row["drive"] == 1 ? 'drive':null;
    $result[] = $row["wikis"] == 1 ? 'wikis':null;
    $result[] = $row["task"] == 1 ? 'task':null;
    $result[] = $row["chat"] == 1 ? 'chat':null;
}

print_r(array_filter($result));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but your answer is in object oriented style. But my application in procedural style. I want to query in procedural style